# Good way of giving a singleton getInstance() method with and without arguments

Tags: singleton

I actually have a singleton class which has two methods getInstance() and getInstance(param1, param2).

getInstance() initializes a singleton object with default values whereas getInstance(param1, param2) initializes a singleton object with user defined parameters (param1 and param2).

But the problem arises when user first calls a getInstance() and do a getInstance(param1, param2) later or viceversa. The same is the case when getInstance(with params) is called twice with different arguments. i.e., getInstance(param1, param2) called first and getInstance(param3, param4) next.

In all the above cases the second call is ignored because a singleton object is initialized only once and it should not be changed again. But, the user will never know all this and would be under the impression that his second call got executed successfully .

Can someone suggest the best way to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Booth methods should return the same instance, just that the second one sets ivas accordingly. There is no need for the user to know about this. Thais the idea about a singelton. If the user really need to know, then return NULL/Nil in an error-case. That way you can tell if the second call was not possible. Still leaves the question why the user needs to know about this. Perhaps a different design strategy will be better?